# What does topsheet in the context of a document (not bedsheet) mean?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

What does topsheet in the context of a document mean? I have also seen it spelt as "top sheet".

Examples of usage:

https://www.studiobinder.com/blog/downloads/film-budget-template/

[image]

I unsuccessfully try to look it up in a dictionary:

- https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/spellcheck/english/?q=topsheet
- https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/spellcheck/english/?q=top%20sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pulled this off [CELTX's blog](https://blog.celtx.com/budgeting-top-sheet/):

> If you’re shopping a project to investors or submitting a budget for approval, the first thing any seasoned producer will ask to see is your Top Sheet. The Top Sheet provides a snapshot of your overall estimated production budget, broken down into four distinct levels which contain financial information on all the accounts necessary for the execution of your project. Top Sheets are effectively universal in their content and absolutely expected.

This is apparently a common term in the film industry for presenting a succinct picture of a proposed project's anticipated budget. It would presumably literally be the top piece of paper on a stack of documents going into further detail of the project's budget requirements.